# Resizing to a higher size from a lower size using Swift's Core Graphics/Quartz Core resizing

Tags: ios, swift, resize, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am trying to resize an image of size 20x20 to an image of 24x24 using Quartz Core resizing technique. I am not able to do so until I give it an image of 24x24, which is the least size it accepts. Following is the code I am using for resizing:

```
  func resizingwithQuadCore24x24(image: UIImage) -> UIImage{
    let cgImage = image.CGImage

    let width = 24
    let height = 24
    let bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgImage)
    let bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImage)
    let colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage)
    let bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(cgImage)

    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, (width), (height), bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    //    print("The infos are bitsPerComponent: \(bitsPerComponent); bytesPerRow: \(bytesPerRow); colorSpace: \(colorSpace); bitmapInfo: \(bitmapInfo) ")
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, CGInterpolationQuality.Default)
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true)
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))), cgImage)

    let scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context).flatMap { UIImage(CGImage: $0) }

    return scaledImage!
}
```

Does anyone knows if it possible to resize an image of lower sizes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to get the bitmap info from the image itself before resizing. This means that the new height and width you pass into the bitmap context will not match the bits per components & bytes per row of the original image.

The solution is to calculate the bits per component and bytes per row based on your new image size. For example:

```
let width = 24
let height = 24
let bitsPerComponent = 8
let bytesPerRow = 4*width
```

This will give you a bitmap with 8 bits per component and 32 bits per pixel.

I would also recommend that you don't get the color space or bitmap info from the image itself – it's normally preferable to work in a bitmap context with a constant format that doesn't depend on the format of the image.

If you want a premultiplied RGBA bitmap context (with 32bpp), you should use the following for the color space and bitmap info:

```
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
```

Finally, I'm not even sure you need to be using a manual bitmap context here, you could just use a `UIGraphics` image context.

For example:

```
// assuming width and height are in pixels here
let width = 24
let height = 24
let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size), cgImage)

let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

---

#### Side Note

I would advise against force unwrapping your `UIImage` at the end of your function, and instead return a `UIImage?`. This will allow the caller of the function deal with the optional nature of the function without crashing your program.

For example:

```
func resizingwithQuadCore24x24(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    ...

    return CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context).map {UIImage(CGImage: $0)}
}
```